# Angular Debug with Source Map active within Intellij IDEA

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I'm trying to enable debug mode in my angular project using Intellij, so after start my project (`npm start`) i created a **JavaScript Debug Configuration**:

[image]

Debuggin in Google Chrome the breakpoint get exactly in place as i expected (my typescript file), but in Intellij IDEA the breakpoint get in a totally different place, look in Intellij:
[image]

I already installed the [JetBrains plugin for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji/related?hl=en) and check if sourceMap is enabled in my `tsconfig.json` but the problem persist:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
...
```

I tried to solve my problem with this post [how to run angular application in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591941/how-to-run-angular-application-in-intellij) but didn't work, the problem continue. Note that in this post the subject is about **run angular project**, i'm already running my project very well, i just want to debug it correctly.

Comment: Have you tried turning on the "Ensure breakpoints are detected when loading scripts" (visible on the first screen)?

Comment: yes, i checked this option but nothing changed.

Comment: On the second screen on the list of remote urls of local files you have an entry with no remote url specified. Does it differ from the File/Directory value of the second entry?

Comment: Yes, this file/directory without remote url is my API (Spring Boot), this is in same workspace my angular project.

Comment: Which versions of angular-cli / IntelliJ do you use?

Comment: Intellij 2018.3 and angular-cli 7.0.5

Comment: debugging angular works just fine here... unfortunately we can hardly help unless you provide a project that can be used to recreate the issue

Comment: I believe source maps are generated by Angular CLI not correctly, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54883663/706012

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular CLI 1.7.0 and Visual Studio Code - can't set breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892311/angular-cli-1-7-0-and-visual-studio-code-cant-set-breakpoints)

Answer (score 0):

The two important things that you need to do in your Javascript D are:

1. Set the Remote URL for your root folder: webpack:///.
2. Set the Remote URL for your src folder: webpack:///.src/

https://itnext.io/debugging-your-angular-application-in-intellij-idea-411a9b08759f